# Display a webview + gallery + webview

Tags: android, layout, webview

I have to implement a layout which I have to show two webviews and a gallety between this. The url for each webview is a html file that I have in local. The gallery have to show images which are storage in local too.

My problems is that when I execute the app only show me the last webview and I can not see the first webview and gallery.

My layout.xml is:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/main_layout" android:scrollbars="vertical">

<!-- Title bar -->
<include android:id="@+id/titlebar" layout="@layout/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/titlebar_height" />


    <!-- Content -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- Content -->
<WebView android:id="@+id/webViewDisease" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</WebView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="180dip" />

<!-- Bottom -->
  <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewBottomDisease" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</WebView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

For my help, I am using textview for separate the differents areas. Maybe the problem is the main scrollbar.

I have try to disable the scrollbar of the webviews by code:

```
this.wbButtom.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
this.wbButtom.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

But I don't work...is imposible show all elements and make scroll.

Any idea?   Thanks y sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iuuhhuuu!!! The solution was super easy...but I didn't know this component: ScrollView.

Ok. put my code; the galery isn't yet but I use a textview between the webviews.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewDisease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></WebView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Bottom -->
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewBottomDisease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </WebView>


 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```